# Object inside bounding box - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the script below I get the outside bounding box.

Script:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
BW = imbinarize(I);
BW2 = imfill(BW,'holes');
imshow(BW2)
s = regionprops(BW2, 'BoundingBox', 'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength', 'Centroid');

for k = 1 : length(s)
  selectCoin = s(k).BoundingBox;
  rectangle('Position', [selectCoin(1),selectCoin(2),selectCoin(3),selectCoin(4)],...
  'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 )
end
```

[image]

is there a way to get the inside bounding box?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you please define what you mean by "inside bounding box"? If you're always working with circles and manage to describe the mathematical relation between the outside bounding box to what you're looking for, you can find the new coordinates of the lines using simple arithmetic from the bounding box parameters

Comment: I used the coin as an example but I wish a general solution for any shape.

Comment: So bounding lines are always either horizontal or vertical? The example shapes you gave have some symmetry, which means there's more than one "red square" that constitutes a "correct solution". In the case of a [crescent](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Crescent.svg) you just want the largest box you can fit inside the shape? I think this can be solved by choosing the coordinates of a point which is inside the shape, then advancing in each direction and checking whether the row/column has `any`/`all` (bounding/bounded, respectively) pixels the color of the shape.

Comment: @Dev-iL and repeat that for every point to look for the largest such box, I presume.

Comment: You're looking for the largest inscribed rectangle. Perhaps [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28155-inscribed-rectangle) will help.